# Correct way of doing it? Reusing same storyboard view and view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am doing like below. The idea is to pass different values and display data based on type supplied from the menu button.

But it is not working as it should. 
It is just displaying which ever view is called first (or data is not refreshed on second button press shows the first view).
So what is the correct way of doing it?

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    SomeViewController* v = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardCat"];
    v.type=@"1";
    [self showViewController:v];
    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
}

if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    SomeViewController* v = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardCat"];
    v.type=@"2";
    [self showViewController:v];
    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
}
```

Edit -for more information
SomeViewController.h file

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@end
```

SomeViewController.m file

```
@implementation SomeViewController
@synthesize type;
arrayData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[CoreDataController getSomeData:type]];

//so trying to populate different values in tableview based on passed parameter to function
```

But now which ever view is called first or value is passed (either 1 or 2), only those values is populated and values does not change on simultaneous call passing another value(for e.g. when index row is 2).

Comment: You are not providing any needed details about `SomeViewController`.

Comment: I have edited the question for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil]; //Change Main if your storyboard name is different.
    SomeViewController* v = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"launchView"]; // launchView is the name given to the view controller in the properties as shown in below screenshot
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: not working. I think i am also doing same thing but for reason tableview is not refreshing on subsequent calls(when done immediately one after another)

Comment: Check to make sure all reload calls are made once first reload is done